# Fastest way to compute a symmetric rank k update with a diagonal matrix

Tags: c, lapack, blas, intel-mkl

I'd like to update a symmetric matrix C with the equation

```
C = alpha*A*D*A^T + beta*C
```

where A is an n by k general matrix and D is a diagonal matrix.

What's the most efficient way to compute this using BLAS and LAPACK? Is there anything similar [syrk](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/dc9/group__single__blas__level3_gae953a93420ca237670f5c67bbde9d9ff.html#gae953a93420ca237670f5c67bbde9d9ff) (netlib) but that allows for a diagonal multiplier? Possibly through a BLAS level-3 extension?

Using MKL, you could compute

```
B = A*D
```

and then use MKL's extension [gemmt](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/blas-like-extensions/gemmt.html) (Intel) to compute only the lower triangular portion of `A * B^T`

But that hardly seems like the most efficient approach possible because the `B = A * D` computation is unnecessary extra work. I'm wondering if there are any specialized kernels for this since it seems like it would be a common computation.